# Slow view with Autolayout enabled - lightning fast without

Tags: ios, performance, constraints, autolayout

I have a view that's swapped into a UIContainerView that is very slow to load (approximatel 1 second).  As a UITabView (not UITabViewController) does the switching, it's quite noticeable for the user as the tab button doesn't update until the view is drawn.

I have determined that this is due to Autolayout.  My app uses storyboards and with Autolayout turned off, the view draws lightning fast (but is completely useless).  I must use Autolayout.

My view contains approximately 35 UISwitch controls laid out on a UIScrollView in sections.  There are also about 10 UITextFields and 1 UITextView.  Each control also has a corresponding label next to it (basically this screen collects Y/N data from the user and few other pieces of textual information...think old-school database like screen with checkboxes which I've replaced with switches).

My speed problem is not due to data loading--as I've said, I've determined that it's 100% an Autolayout problem when the view is drawn.

I have tried everything from flattening the layout (all controls sitting right on top of the UIScrollView) to creating a view hierarchy (all controls from each section and subsection inside UIViews, inside other UIViews, sitting on top of the UIScrollView).  The subview version is definitely faster since having the controls loose on the UIView took more like 2 seconds to update.

I've also re-constrained it many times and believe I've found the least number of self-generated constraints to allow for device rotation, and then I used the "Add Missing Constraints" function to add the remainder to eliminate warnings/errors in Autolayout.  Most of my self-generated ones were simply "equal widths" constraints on side-by-side labels and UITextViews to have them stretch horizontally when in landscape orientation.

I've read comments here and in other places regarding drawing the view off-screen and then just presenting it.  Since I'm swapping the view(s) in and out of a UIContainerView this seems like a good suggestion, but I can't find any description on how to do this.  I'm already instantiating it during its view controller's ViewDidLoad and not swapping it in until the correct tab button is hit.

What else do I need to do to get it to "draw" offscreen to maybe help with this speed issue?

(Please no suggestions to reduce the number of controls on-screen or to use concurrency to load the data in the background.  I must have all the controls in this one view and the data load is not a problem.  I also cannot use a table view in place of this scroll view.)

Thanks very much.

EDIT - Visual:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   |
|   +-----Section 1---------------------------+     |
|   |   label |SW|   label |SW|  label |SW|   |     |
|   |   label |___textField___|  label |SW|   |     |   This is an approximate version
|   |   label |SW|   label |SW|  label |SW|   |     |   of the layout.  There are a number
|   +-----------------------------------------+     |   sections and subsections, and a 
|                                                   |   number of UISwitches, UITextFields,
|                                                   |   and labels for each one.
|   +-----Section 2---------------------------+     |
|   |   label |SW|   label |SW|  label |SW|   |     |   Each section has a colored or
|   |   label |___textField___|  label |SW|   |     |   graphical background.
|   |   label |SW|   label |SW|  label |SW|   |     |
|   |   label |SW|   label |SW|  label |SW|   |     |
|   |   label |SW|   label |SW|  label |SW|   |     |
|   |   label |SW|   label |___textField__|   |     |
|   +-----------------------------------------+     |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|   +-----Section 3---------------------------+     |
|   |   label |SW|   label |SW|  label |SW|   |     |      Somewhere around here is the
|   |   label |___textField___|  label |SW|   |     |      bottom of the iPad screen and the
|   |   label |SW|   label |___textField__|   |     |      rest scrolls as this is all
|   +-----------------------------------------+     |      inside a large UIScrollView.
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|   +-----Section 4---------------------------+     |
|   |   +---Subsection A-------------------+  |     |
|   |   |      label |SW|    label |SW|    |  |     |
|   |   |      label |__textField___|      |  |     |
|   |   |      label |__textField___|      |  |     |
|   |   +----------------------------------+  |     |
|   |   +---Subsection B-------------------+  |     |
|   |   |      label |SW|    label |SW|    |  |     |
|   |   |      label |__textField___|      |  |     |
|   |   |      label |__textField___|      |  |     |
|   |   +----------------------------------+  |     |
|   |   +---Subsection C-------------------+  |     |
|   |   |      label |SW|    label |SW|    |  |     |
|   |   |      label |__textField___|      |  |     |
|   |   |      label |__textField___|      |  |     |
|   |   +----------------------------------+  |     |
|   +-----------------------------------------+     |
|                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: A screenshot would be nice. My gut suggestion would be to use something like a table view or collection view, but you haven't said _why_ that's not an option. If you're looking at subviews in the hundreds, Autolayout is going to struggle.

Comment: It's a spread out layout with items side-by-side.  I'll add a visual to the original post above.